# Multi task learning in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

I am trying to implement shared layers in Keras. I do see that Keras has `keras.layers.concatenate`, but I am unsure from documentation about its use. Can I use it to create multiple shared layers? What would be the best way to implement a simple shared neural network as shown below using Keras? [image: Shared Neural network]

---

**Edit 1:**
Note that all the shape of input, output and shared layers for all 3 NNs are the same. There are multiple shared layers (and non-shared layers) in the three NNs. The coloured layers are unique to each NN, and have same shape.

Basically, the figure represents 3 identical NNs with multiple shared hidden layers, followed by multiple non-shared hidden layers.

I am unsure how to share multiple layers as in the Twitter example, there was just one shared layer (example in API doc).

---

**Edit 2:**
Based on geompalik's helpful comments, this is what I initially came up with:

```
sharedLSTM1 = LSTM((data.shape[1]), return_sequences=True)
sharedLSTM2 = LSTM(data.shape[1])
def createModel(dropoutRate=0.0, numNeurons=40, optimizer='adam'):
    inputLayer = Input(shape=(timesteps, data.shape[1]))
    sharedLSTM1Instance = sharedLSTM1(inputLayer)
    sharedLSTM2Instance =  sharedLSTM2(sharedLSTM1Instance)
    dropoutLayer = Dropout(dropoutRate)(sharedLSTM2Instance)
    denseLayer1 = Dense(numNeurons)(dropoutLayer)
    denseLayer2 = Dense(numNeurons)(denseLayer1)
    outputLayer = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(denseLayer2)
    return (inputLayer, outputLayer)

inputLayer1, outputLayer1 = createModel()
inputLayer2, outputLayer2 = createModel()
model = Model(inputs=[inputLayer1, inputLayer2], outputs=[outputLayer1, outputLayer2])
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

In the above code, I expect that the LSTM Layers in the two models are shared, whereas the dropout and 2 dense layers are not shared. Is that correct?

If so, I do not need `keras.layers.concatenate` in this example, right?

I get the following image if I try to visualise the network using `plot_model` (which is what I was expecting):

[image: model plot]

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want all three color layers to share weights and have the same structure?

Comment: I have updated the question to include the information. The documentation on `keras.layers.concatenate` is limited. I could not find any tutorial about sharing layers either. I think the post can be beneficial for beginners who are trying to understand sharing layers in keras.  I would appreciate if the post is not closed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implementing the shown architecture is quite straight-forward with the functional API of Keras.  [Check this page](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) for more information on that.

In your case you have the input layer and the first hidden layer shared, and then one layer for each of the three subjects. Designing your model is now a matter of how your data look: for instance, if for a given input you have different outputs for each subject, you can should define a model like:

```
model = Model(inputs=[you_main_input], outputs=[subject1_output, subject2_output, subject3_output])
```

If that is not the case, and you have training data corresponding to each of the subjects, you can define three NNs, and have the first two layers shared across them. Check under "Shared layers" in the above-cited documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did try read the API document. But how can I “share” layers in two NN. I am unable to find any tutorial regarding “concatenate”. My input and output have the same shape. But I need 2-3 shared layers, not just one.

Comment: Basically, the figure represents 3 identical NNs with multiple shared hidden layers, followed by multiple non-shared hidden layers. The twitter example just had one shared layer, and I am unsure about the implementation because of lack of tutorials.

Comment: The fact that you have multiple shared layers does not really change anything. Instead of the single LSTM of the example in the docs, in your case you use more layers. And you define 3 networks, one for each non-shared output part. Then, each time you back-prop, you will update both the shared weights, and the output specific ones

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have updated the question with code and would really appreciate your review.

Comment: I do not think you need `concatenate`. I think you should also pass the `sharedLSTM` as args to the function though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But the current model does work too, right? I simply need to do `model.fit([data1, data2], [labels1, labels2])` to train it, right?

Comment: This seems to be the case, yes.

Comment: are these data1 and data2 are different in terms of the number of features, samples, and classes?